# Highcharts update series performance issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was hoping to pick your brains on a highcharts performance issue.

I have a script that is looping an event 500 times over 30 seconds. Those events will occur at random times across the 30 seconds -but as you can guess the frequency is pretty high. Each time the event occurs I am updating a series on a highchart. I update the series like so:

```
var previousValue = chart.series[0].data[1]; 
chart.series[0].data[1].update(previousValue + 1);
```

Unfortunately it looks like the high frequency of updates is crashing my browser window. When I remove the update chart feature my code runs perfectly well and does not crash. Any ideas as to how I can improve performance or get around this annoying issue?

Kind regards,
G.

Comment: You are not updating series, but each point's value. Have you considered using [`Series.setData(array)`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData)? Additionally, if you update multiple points at the same time, then set `redraw` param to false: `update(value, false)`. Once all updates are done, call `chart.redraw()` to redraw the chart just once.

Comment: Hello Pawel, thanks for your answer. The reason I am updating the chart as such is to provide an animation. I want the increment to be visualized from beginning to end.

Comment: Still, call `chart.redraw()` just once.